# 0/1 knapsack recursive solution

Tags: recursion, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to understand this question on leetcode
[Partition Equal subset problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/)

The solution section has recommended a naive approach to recurse, in one part it suggests this:

```
isSum (subSetSum, n) = isSum(subSetSum- nums[n], n-1) ||  isSum(subSetSum, n-1)
```

But in the sample code, the recursion logic is set as:

```
bool result = dfs(nums, n - 1, subSetSum - nums[n - 1]) || dfs(nums, n - 1, subSetSum);
```

Why is it that in the solution we're subtracting nums[n] and in the final solution we're subtracting nums[n-1]. And which one is the right solution ? I tried and both seem to be giving the right result, something is wrong here but I cannot see what.

Any suggestions ?